# How to enforce F[_] to be an instance of Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have the following class definition:

```
final case class Creator[F[_]](topic: String, discovery: ServiceDiscovery[F])
                                     (implicit sync: Sync[F]) {
  import JsonDeserializer._

  private def setting: ConsumerSettings[F, String, JsonDecoder] =
     discovery
       .kafkaAddr
```

I would like to enforce `F[_]` to be an instance of `Monad`, that I can use `flatMap` like:

```
 private def setting: ConsumerSettings[F, String, JsonDecoder] =
     discovery
       .kafkaAddr
       .flatMap.......
```

How can I archive it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import syntax

```
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
```

Since `cats.effect.Sync` extends `cats.Monad` (and `cats.FlatMap`) and you have `implicit sync: Sync[F]` this should be enough.