# Make F[_] implementing Monad trait while accepting IO

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, scala-cats, cats-effect

Let us say we have the code (`<: Monad[F]` doesn't work as expected):

```
class External[F[_] <: Monad[F] : Concurrent](implicit proxy: Proxy[F]) { ... }

class Proxy[F[_] <: Monad[F]](implicit storage: Storage, async: Async[F]) {
  def get(key: String): F[Option[Entry]] = {
    async.blocking(storage.get(key))
  }
}
```

I would like `F[_]` to be a `Monad`, so that `proxy.get()` have those traits and enables for example (inside `External` class):

```
proxy.get(key).flatMap(...)
```

So far so good, but when trying to instantiate with `cats.effect.IO` it doesn't work for `External`:

```
implicit val proxy: Proxy[IO] = new Proxy()
implicit val external: External[IO] = new External()
```

With error output:

```
inferred type arguments [[+A]cats.effect.IO[A]] do not conform to value <local External>'s type parameter bounds [F[_] <: cats.Monad[F]]
```

How can this be fixed or achieved in a different way?

Comment: `IO` IS NOT A `Monad`, nor are `List`, `Either`, `Option`, or whatever other data type you may think it is. They all FORM A `Monad` _(another way of saying it is that they have an instance of a `Monad` associated with them)_. This is one of the main differences between a **typeclass** and traditional **subtyping**, and this is important to understand so you can see why `F[_] : Monad` works while `F[_] <: Monad` doesn't. - BTW, this is easier to see if you remove sugar syntax: `class External[_](implicit ev1: Monad[F], ev2: Concurrent[F])`; PS: `Concurrent` IS A `Monad` thus you only need that

Comment: Also, if you are pretty new to all this I would recommend sticking to concrete `IO` for a while before diving deep into what is commonly known as _"tagless final"_ Anyways, feel free to join the **typelevel** discord server where you may ask for more guidance on this style.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Correct preposition was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477132 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
class External[F[_] <: Monad[F] : Concurrent]
```

with

```
class External[F[_]: Monad : Concurrent]
```

Being a `Monad` doesn't mean being a subtype of `Monad`. It means there is an instance of the type class `Monad` for current type.

On contrary to OOP, in FP implementing some abstract behavior is achieved not with extending/inheritance/subtype polymorphism but with implicits/defining type-class instances/*ad hoc* polymorphism.

Maybe you need to import necessary syntax:

```
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
```

or

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
```

or all synaxes at once

```
import cats.syntax.all._
```

[How to enforce F[_] to be an instance of Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150448/how-to-enforce-f-to-be-an-instance-of-monad)

https://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/import-guide.html

Comment: Not sufficient, since then `proxy.get()` will not have `Monad` traits.

Comment: @scala-n00b Not sure I understand. Please update your code with current version reflecting current problem. What doesn't compile?

Comment: proxy.get(key): Cannot resolve symbol flatMap

Comment: @scala-n00b Can't reproduce https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/mMaQ7tgDRei8yW0HvSbebg/7 Please write the whole code.

Comment: @scala-n00b Maybe you need to import syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150448/how-to-enforce-f-to-be-an-instance-of-monad

Comment: Not about import syntax either I think. This works without generics use works perfectly fine: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/W9MDWWdrTfS5UBBkRjePTA but with generics: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9ddYUoGPRLaSmespG2luuQ not so much

Comment: @scala-n00b No, this is exactly because of importing syntax. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/UjF8GBFRTlqF3ZHiO2eTOw/1 Just `Functor` syntax, not `FlatMap` syntax.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: @scala-n00b is usually better to just `import cats.syntax.all._` since that way you will get all the syntax and you don't need to care about exactly which part of the hierarchy provides it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's a good remark although I normally prefer to have more control on what implicits are imported to the scope https://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/import-guide.html Sometimes something just starts to break. (Also it can be convenient for debugging implicits)

Comment: @DmytroMitin well to each one their own, I tried to follow _"a la carte"_ imports when learning and sooner than latter I found it just being a lot of work and extra changes on commits / PRs without any value at all. Also, for what I have seen in the **discord** server the general guideline is also to just import everything, it is even in the [FAQ](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#what-imports) _(although the code is outdated, I will open a PR in a moment)_. - IMHO, t is just way simpler to just import `all` that way you fave yourself from discussions like why even `FlatMap` is a thing?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok but sometimes there can be conflicts with your own syntaxes and syntaxes of libraries different from Cats.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Agree, I think my previous comment is missing a _"beginners"_ somewhere :)